# php multidimensional array issue

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

I am pulling in an XML feed from a blogger blog and need to parse it using PHP. The data looks something like this, once I have used the simplexml_load_file() function:

```
["entry"]=> array(25) {["link"]=> array(5) {[4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#571 (1) {["@attributes"]=> array(4) {["rel"]=> string(9) "alternate"
```

When I try to target rel like so:

```
echo $xmldata[0]->entry[0]->link[4]->@attributes['rel'];
```

and

```
echo $xmldata[0]->entry[0]->link[4]->[@attributes]->rel;
```

I get the following errors:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

and

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

respectively.

Any ideas?

Comment: probably you need quotes `echo $xmldata[0]->entry[0]->link[4]->["@attributes"]->rel;`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
echo $xmldata[0]->entry[0]->link[4]['rel'];
```

The [Basic SimpleXML usage documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) (example #5) shows how an element's attributes can be accessed just like an associative array as in the above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `@attributes` in curly braces and in `''` quotes.

```
echo $xmldata[0]->entry[0]->link[4]->{'@attributes'}['rel']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `@` is a [keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) you need to wrap the identifier into curly brackets:

```
echo $xmldata[0]
  ->entry[0]
  ->link[4]
  ->{'@attributes'}['rel'];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little bit confused here. Could you briefly explain why my answer is considered inferior or not useful? Trying to learn...

Comment: Well you should ask the downvoter, anyway, I suppose it's wrong because at `link[4]` there's an object, this object has a property called `@attributes` which is an array that contains `rel`, the problem is that being `@` a keyword you can't access it so `->@attributes`, for this you need to have brackets and single quotes around the identifier. Your answer bypass the `@attributes` identifier, also if there was a property called `rel` you would have used `link[4]->rel` since at `link[4]` there's an object.

Comment: OK. Thanks for answering. According to the [Basic SimpleXML documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and my own tests, index-based access works fine for attributes though.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, although there's no xml example with attributes in the documentation, at least I don't see it.

Comment: Example #5 Using attributes

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I actually didn't know that.